# Ways to look at a polyhedral graph

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

#### Motivation

There are at least three *interpretations* of an abstract polyhedral (= planar 3-vertex-connected) graph:

- the **1-skeleton of a convex polyhedron** (when embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$)
- a **polygonization of the sphere** (when embedded into the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$)
- a **polygonization of a polygon** – for each of its faces (when embedded into the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$)

In any case there are many geometric *realizations*:

- of a polyhedron
- of a polygonization of the sphere
- of a polygon and its polygonizations

#### Question

I'd like to understand in an abstract setting:

> What do these interpretations and realizations have to do with each
> other?

#### Example

For many (but not all) polyhedral graphs there is a realization as a convex polyhedron that is [inscribable](https://digital.lib.washington.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1773/2276/Graphs%20of%20polyhedra.pdf;jsessionid=722305F151F9B613CC1379D5C04FF5B7?sequence=1) into the sphere. A central projection of this polyhedron back onto the sphere induces a polygonization of the sphere.

Taken for granted is [Steinitz' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem). The question is *not* about this.

---

**EDIT**: For completeness' sake I should mention embeddings of a polyhedral graph into:

- the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^2$
- the 3-dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$
- the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^3$

Comment: Dear Hans, what do you mean by a polygon and its polygonizations?

Comment: Quite simple: every embedding of a planar graph into $\mathbb{R}^2$ has an outer face - "the polygon" - which is "polygonized" by the rest of the graph.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, just a pointer on one aspect of your question,
the relationship between two of your three "interpretations."
As you note, not all polyhedral graphs have
a realization that is inscribable in a sphere.  Here is an explicit example:

> "Uninscribable 4-Regular Polyhedron."
>   *Electronic Geometry Model No. 2003.08.001*.
>   David Eppstein and Michael Dillencourt.
>   ([Link to abstract, and to the images below](http://www.eg-models.de/models/Polytopes/2003.08.001/_preview.html))

[image]
    
[image]

There is a characterization of the inscribable polyhedral graphs, obtained in 1992:

> Craig Hodgson, Igor Rivin, and Warren Smith.
>   "A characterization of convex hyperbolic polyhedra and of convex polyhedra inscribed in the sphere."
>   ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.MG/9210218))

---

Now that I understand better the thrust of the question from the OP's comment below,
I believe this recent survey by Günter Rote should be helpful:

> "Realizing Planar Graphs as Convex Polytopes."
>   *Graph Drawing*.
>   Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 7034, 2012, pp 238-241.
>   ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-25878-7_23?LI=true))

Comment: @Joseph Thank you for the representation of polyhedrons by differently colored (shaded) faces and vertices. This helps a lot. Can this be automated (given an abstract polyhedral graph)?

Comment: @Hans: I have used Tutte's embedding theorem: Every 3-connected planar graph can be straight-line embedded in the plane so that each face is convex and each vertex a wheel. I'll add a reference to my answer.

Comment: For those who don't have a Springer account: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rote/Papers/slides/Realizing+planar+graphs+as+convex+polytopes--Graph-Drawing-2011-Eindhoven.pdf

Comment: @Joseph: Do you know of a comparable result for inscribable polyhedral graphs in flat space $\mathbb{R}^3$? (I am not so familiar with hyperbolic space and have a lack of imagination.)

Comment: @Joseph: BTW, the second reference (to Rote) is a late answer to another question of mine: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119455/visualizing-polyhedra-from-their-1-skeletons. Thanks a lot for this one, too!

Comment: @Hans: I believe that Hodgson et al. paper *does* characterize inscribable graphs in $\mathbb{E}^3$, i.e., in "flat space $\mathbb{R}^3$."