# Polyhedra Classification

Tags: co.combinatorics, polyhedra

The following is inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119455/visualizing-polyhedra-from-their-1-skeletons). From time to time I search the web for tables of polyhedra, but without much success. Part of the problem is that there are many non-equivalent questions that can be asked. For example:

- If $G$ is a planar graph where every edge is in a cycle, what extra conditions are needed so that $G$ realizable as a polyhedron?
- How many polyhedra with $e$ edges are there?
- If $G$ is a planar graph where every edge is in a cycle, what extra conditions are needed so that $G$ realizable as a polyhedron with regular faces?
- How many polyhedra with $e$ edges and regular faces are there?
- What are the obstructions to realizability?
- etc$\ldots$

> **Meta-question:** Where are questions like these addressed?

Comment: To your questions including regular faces: such polyhedra are called [*Johnson solids*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid) and are completely enumerated (e.g. in the linked Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are three sources, specifically on convex polyhedra (and polytopes), 
followed (now) by one reference on nonconvex polyhedra.
These by no means constitute a complete answer to your broad question.

The classic source is:

> Branko Grünbaum. *Convex Polytopes*, 2nd ed. New York: Springer-Verlag, 2003.
>   ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387404090))

A modern treatment:

> Günter M. Ziegler. *Lectures on Polytopes*. Graduate Texts in Mathematics 152. Springer-Verlag New York Berlin Heidelberg, Revised sixth printing 2006. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8431-1/page/1))

Finally,
the integer sequence
[A000944](http://oeis.org/A000944) counts the number of convex polyhedra with $n$ vertices
(and cites Grünbaum).

---

In response to Dima's question, let me add:

> Branko Grünbaum.
>   "Graphs of polyhedra; polyhedra as graphs."
>   *Discrete Mathematics*.
>   Volume 307, Issues 3–5, 6 February 2007, Pages 445–463.
>   ([Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X06005279))

He says, "The central obstacle to any coherent theory of polyhedra more general than the
convex ones is the difficulty of defining precisely what objects should be awarded that
designation."

 [image]
Here is the abstract:

> Relations between graph theory and polyhedra are presented in two
>   contexts. In the first, the symbiotic dependence between 3-connected
>   planar graphs and convex polyhedra is described in detail. In the second,
>   a theory of nonconvex polyhedra is based on a graph-theoretic
>   foundation. This approach eliminates the vagueness and inconsistency
>   that pervade much of the literature dealing with polyhedra more general
>   than the convex ones.

Comment: I wonder if anyone looked at the non-convex case.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik unfortunately, not really.

Answer (score 3):

One more article (it is absent in the book of Grünbaum):

Bilinski, Stanko
Über die Ordnungszahl der Klassen Eulerscher Polyeder.
Arch. Math. 10, 180-186 (1959).